# Call the super constructors of parent classes in python

Tags: python

I have two classes that I want to inherit *class A* and *class B*, each requiring different values as arguments. How can I do that?

```
class A:
def __init__(self, a1, a2):
    print('A.__init__')
    super(A, self).__init__()
    
    self.a1 = a1
    self.a2 = a2

class B:
    def __init__(self, b):
        print('B.__init__')
        super(B, self).__init__()
    
        self.b = b

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self, a1, a2, b):
        print('C.__init__')
        # call A.__init__(a1, a2)
        # call B.__init__(b)
```

Comment: and  remove ` super(A, self).__init__()` from class A and  `super(B, self).__init__()` from class B

Comment: Oh no, this option gives the following error 

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'
```

Comment: You can also use A.__init__(self, a1, a2), you were missing that self reference

Comment: @sittsering The first suggestion won't actually work (``super`` doesn't know that the ``a1, a2`` belong to A). The second goes completely against the point of cooperative inheritance (*every* method along the chain must invoke ``super`` to be cooperative).

Comment: @sittsering, I cannot change class A and class B

Comment: @kostas19 If the classes aren't designed for multiple inheritance and you cannot change them, then you simply can't reliably use them with multiple inheritance. Have you considered composition over inheritance?

Comment: @m.oulmakki, A.__init__(self, a1, a2) also gives an error `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'` and asks to pass b to the constructor of class A

Comment: @kostas19 `B.__init__(self, b)`

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, to be honest, I haven't been working with python very long and was hoping to be able to use these classes as parents

Comment: @m.oulmakki, yes, I can call the constructor of class B. But when i calling a constructor of class A in this way calls a constructor of class B, which is not the behavior I expect